# What's wrong with my base 10 or code in general

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple color game but can't get it to work right.

```
import random
color = ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow"]

name = input('Hi,Whats your name?')
print ("Well",name, "I am thinking of a color, can you guess it?")

guess1 = int(input()) # convert input from string to integer

while guess1 != color:    
    if guess1 > color:
        print ('Wrong color.')
    guess1 = int(input())  # asks user to take another guess

    print("Good job, you got it!")
```

At base 10 there is an error with color.

Comment: please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It appears you are attempting to get collect an input, convert to int and then see if the converted int does not match a string array.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

# All colors we are checking
colors = ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow"]
# Select one random color
target_color = random.choice(colors)

name = input('Hi,Whats your name?')
print ("Well", name, "I am thinking of a color, can you guess it?")

# Get input as a string
guess = input()

# While we are wrong
while guess != target_color:
    print ('Wrong color.')
    # We try to check another color
    guess = input()

print("Good job, you got it!")
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: If my answer helped you, I will be appreciated if you will upvote/accept my answer :)